# Prove that if $⟨u,w⟩=⟨v,w⟩$ for all $w \in V$ then $u=v$ where $V$ is vectorial space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

1) Prove that if $\langle u,w \rangle= \langle v,w \rangle$ for all $w \in V$ then $u=v$ where $V$ is vectorial space.

2)Prove that if $\langle w,u \rangle= \langle w,v \rangle$ for all $w \in V$ then $u=v$ where $V$ is vectorial space.

In $V$ vectorial space we define $\langle  \rangle:V$x$V \rightarrow K$, $K$ field; where ($u,v$) $\rightarrow \langle u,v \rangle$. Wight the following properties:

i) $\langle au+v,w \rangle=a\langle u,w \rangle+\langle v,w \rangle$ for all $u,v \in V$ and for all $a\in K$.

ii) $\langle u,v\rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$ for all $u,v \in V$

iii) $\langle u,u\rangle$>$0$ for all $u \in V$, $u$ non-zero.

We don't define for operation subtraction or equality for inner product so I don't see the relationship between components. Could you help? please.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for the delimeters, not `<` and `>`. The latter are binary relations, so they don’t render well. Compare $\langle u,v\rangle$ with $<u,v>$.

Comment: Note: you mean “prove that if $\langle u,w\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle$ for all $w$ in $V$ then $u=v$”. What you wrote is different (you wrote: “prove that $(\langle u,w\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle \implies u=v)$ for all $w\in V$“; that is false, since the case $w=0$ satisfies the premise but not necessarily the conclusion of the implication. Thta is, you wrote that you want to prove that for **each** $w$ you can go from $\langle u,w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$ to $u=v$, whereas you are being asked to prove that you can go from ($\langle u,w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$ for all $w$) to $u=v$.

Comment: “We don’t define for operation subtraction or equality for inner products”. Note that the result of an inner product is a scalar, and we know how to subtract and compare scalars. The expression $\langle u,w\rangle - \langle v,w\rangle$ is perfectly sensible: it is the difference of two scalars. As for vectors, note that $u-v = u+(-v)$, so $\langle u-v,w\rangle = \langle u+(-v),w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle + \langle -v,w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle +(-\langle v,w\rangle) = \langle u,w\rangle - \langle v,w\rangle$.

Comment: But we can't compare by any definition components by components

Comment: But you can pick a specific value of $w$ to conclude that $u-v$ must be equal to $0$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Since $\langle u,w\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle$ for all $w$, then it follows that
$$\langle u-v,w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle - \langle v,w\rangle = 0$$
for all $w$. What if $w=u-v$?

Answer (score 0):

Another proof of this that isn't quite as nice as the one Arturo alluded to is to choose an orthonormal basis for $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard inner product, we have

$$ (v_1,\dots,v_n) \cdot \mathbf{e}_i = v_i$$

So if $v \cdot \mathbf{e}_i = u \cdot \mathbf{e}_i$ for all $i$ then $v$ and $u$ have the same components.

Comment: Of course, that only works for inner product spaces that have orthonormal bases (e.g., finite dimensional ones), while the statement holds for any inner product space, even infinite dimensional ones like $\ell_2$.